# Spring Boot PageNotFound - No mapping for GET/ POST

Tags: spring-boot, rest, build.gradle, corretto

After Upgrading my application from

**Java 1.7** to **openjdk version "11.0.2" Corretto-11.0.2.9.3**

**SpringBoot 1.3.7.RELEASE** to **SpringBoot 2.1.1.RELEASE**

**Gradle 2.10** to **Gradle 5.2**

> I am getting HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error in postman after making a GET or POST calls.

**For GET request i am getting below warning in logs:**

> PageNotFound - No mapping for GET
>
> ServletRequestLoggerFilter - Failed to parse response body error: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 2]

**For POST request i am getting below warning in logs:**

> POST request body is JSON
>
> ServletRequestLoggerFilter - Failed to parse response body error: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number,
>       String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
>        at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 2]

```
Where as all the REST calls were working before upgrade.
```

Comment: can you share the @RestController method and RequestBody

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String getStatus() {
        return "Hello";
    }

Comment: YOU SHARED A GET METHOD  IN THE COMMENT BUT IN THE QUESTION YOU HAVE SAID ITS AN POST REQUEST

Comment: I have added for both GET and POST in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It worked as i was upgrading from an older version of spring boot so the property got changed from Old property- server.context-path New property- server.servlet.context-path